# Translation of context-free parsing into SAT

Tags: fl.formal-languages, sat

Is there a published algorithm for translating a context-free parsing problem into SAT? That is, an algorithm that translates a context-free grammar and an input string into a set clauses that is satisfiable iff the input string is well-formed according to the grammar.

Comment: I do not know. There is a somewhat related translation of a CFG Ginto a Presburger formula for the Parikh image of L(G) in Theorem 4 o:f Kumar Neeraj Verma, Helmut Seidl, Thomas Schwentick: On the Complexity of Equational Horn Clauses. CADE 2005:337-352 (DOI:10.1007/11532231_25)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

(I guess the important word in the original question is ``published''.)  There is such an encoding of context-free parsing (more exactly of CYK-style parsing) in  Roland Axelsson, Keijo Heljanko, and Martin Lange, *Analyzing Context-Free Grammars Using an Incremental SAT Solver*, ICALP 2008, Lecture Notes in Computer Science vol. 5126, pp. 410--422, [doi:10.1007/978-3-540-70583-3_34](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-540-70583-3_34).  They use it in particular to detect ambiguity of words $w$ in context-free grammars for growing word lengths.

Answer (score 0):

here is a similar/ more recent ref (2014) using the technique on probabilistic CFGs. (but they seem to skip over details of the SAT solver...?)

[Grammatical Inference of some Probabilistic Context-Free Grammars from Positive Data using Minimum Satisfiability](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/proceedings/papers/v34/scicluna14a.pdf) / Scicluna, Higuera

> Recently, different theoretical learning results have been found for a variety of context-free grammar subclasses through the use of distributional learning (Clark, 2010b). However, these results are still not extended to probabilistic grammars. In this work, we give a practical algorithm, with some proven properties, that learns a subclass of probabilistic grammars from positive data. A minimum satisfiability solver is used to direct the search towards small grammars. Experiments on typical context-free languages and artificial natural language grammars give positive results.